# How to match immediately previous word pattern in java?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string like this :

```
"value of <abc/def> ends with <def> and value of <abc/def> does not end with <abc> and value of <abc> is <abc>"
```

I want to extract the string `value of <abc/def> does not end with <abc>`. 
I used following pattern

```
String text = "value of <abc/def> ends with <def> and value of <abc/def> does not end with <abc> and value of <abc> is <abc>";
String patternString1 = "(value\\s+of\\s+(<.*>)\\s+ends\\s+with\\s+(<.*>))";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(patternString1);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(text);
while(matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println("found: " + matcher.group(1));
}
```

Results :-

```
found: value of <abc/def> ends with <def> and value of <abc/def> does not end with <abc> and value of <abc> is <abc>
```

Comment: `.*` is [greedy](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2301285/2071828) by default. You would need to make it lazy by adding a `?`. At least I think that is the issue - I don't really understand the question.

Comment: I don't really know what you really mean but maybe modifying the greed of the `*` will do the trick, to `*?`. This will grab the least characters possible.

Comment: Why is your regex trying to match the `ends with`-part whereas you say, you want to match the `does not end with`-part? It's somehow confusing.

Answer (score 2):

As you mean to get `value of <abc/def> does not end with <abc>` the pattern after the correction:

```
String patternString1 = "(value\\s+of\\s+(<[^>]*>)\\s+does\\s+not\\s+end\\s+with\\s+(<[^>]*>))";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below code for this.

```
String text = "value of ends with and value of does not end with and value of is ";
String arr[] = text.split(" and ");
System.out.println(arr[1]);
```

This splits string into three parts.This would help you.

Comment: Thanks...But the problem is all the characters between <> are variables. any string can come. like <abc> or <def> or <xyzzzz>. So we cam't use static string to split.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.endsWith()`

```
if (!<abc/def>.endsWith(<abc>) {
   // do stuff ...
}
```

I put the `!` so it only happens when it doesn't end with